# How to use do while loop of the u8g library in page drawing mode

Tags: rotary-encoder, debounce, oled, u8glib

I am trying to use a rotary encoder with 128x64 OLED display on an Arduino nano. I am trying to create a menu that can be scrolled through using the rotary encoder. While testing the rotary encoder, I found out it bounces quite a lot, so I used Bounce2 library and few extra lines of code to get the encoder working properly.

https://wokwi.com/projects/393512353441494017
here's the wokwi simulation and code of just the rotary encoder and I have tested this code on real hardware and it works fine.

```cpp
    #include <Bounce2.h>
    #include "U8glib.h"
    #define ENCODER_CLK 3
    #define ENCODER_DT 2
    #define ENCODER_SW 4
    
    //buttons
    Bounce2::Button encoder_clk = Bounce2::Button();
    Bounce2::Button encoder_dt = Bounce2::Button();
    Bounce2::Button encoder_sw = Bounce2::Button();
    #define LED_PIN 13
    
    bool led_state = LOW;
    
    void setup() {
      
      //serial monitor
      Serial.begin(115200);
      
      //encoder and button debouncing
      encoder_clk.attach( ENCODER_CLK, INPUT);
      encoder_dt.attach( ENCODER_DT, INPUT);
      encoder_sw.attach( ENCODER_SW, INPUT_PULLUP);
      
      encoder_clk.interval(5);
      encoder_dt.interval(5);
      encoder_sw.interval(5);
    
      encoder_clk.setPressedState(LOW);
      encoder_dt.setPressedState(LOW);
      encoder_sw.setPressedState(LOW);
      
      //test led
      pinMode(LED_PIN,OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN,led_state);
      
    
    }
    
    
    void loop() {
      
      encoder_clk.update();
      encoder_dt.update();
      encoder_sw.update();
      
      if (encoder_clk.changed()) {
        // There was a change on the CLK pin
        bool dtValue = encoder_dt.read();
        bool ckValue = encoder_clk.read();
        if (ckValue == LOW && dtValue == HIGH) {
          Serial.println("Rotated clockwise ⏩");
        }
        if (ckValue == LOW && dtValue == LOW) {
          Serial.println("Rotated counterclockwise ⏪");
        }
      }
    
      if(encoder_sw.pressed()){
        led_state = !led_state;
         digitalWrite(LED_PIN, led_state);
         Serial.println("Button Pressed");
      }
    }
```

Then I decided to test the OLED display.
Here is the wokwi simulation for oled and rotatry encoder together.
https://wokwi.com/projects/393400062063669249

After adding the code for OLED display and the do while loop of u8g library, it has stopped registering rotary encoder inputs. I cannot get any thing displayed on serial monitor. I have tested this on real hardware as well and the result is the same. How do I fix this problem and what would be the better way to use the do while loop of the u8g library?

Comment: Cross posted at forum.arduino.cc and getting attention there.  https://forum.arduino.cc/t/do-while-loop-of-u8g-page-drawing-mode-stops-everything-else-in-void-loop/1240533

Comment: Voting to close for the cross post and because the code posted doesn't include the do-while construct that the OP is saying he has problems with.

Comment: why do you require the use of a `do while` loop? ... this appears to be a an XY problem ... asking about a perceived solution to an unspecified problem, instead of asking about the problem itself ... please edit the title to ask about the actual problem that you are trying  to solve

Answer (score 1):

For reliably registering encoder transition, you need your main loop to
be non-blocking. My guess is that the `do...while` loop blocks the
Arduino for too long. If this is the case, one possible solution is to
perform a single iteration of this `do...while` loop inside `loop()`.
For instance, your current `loop()` looks like this:

```cpp
void loop() {
    handle_the_encoder();

    u8g.firstPage();
    do {
        do_the_drawing();
    } while (u8g.nextPage());
}
```

You can change it into this:

```cpp
void loop() {
    handle_the_encoder();

    static bool do_first_page = true;
    if (do_first_page) {
        u8g.firstPage();
        do_first_page = false;
    }
    do_the_drawing();
    if (!u8g.nextPage())
        do_first_page = true;
}
```

If needed, you may also break the drawing code into smaller chunks, and
do a single chunk per loop iteration. This will require you implementing
a [finite state machine](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine).